# WebApp Deployment on ServiceMix

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have read a lot, tried a lot but I can not solve this thing. The problem is, I am trying to deploy war file in Service mix, but it prompts for the following error:

> 04:32:26,792 | DEBUG | mix-4.5.1/deploy | HttpServiceContext
>   | 117 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 1.0.12.1 | found resource:
>   null 04:32:26,792 | DEBUG | mix-4.5.1/deploy | AbstractLifeCycle
>   | 112 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.5.4.v20111024 | STARTED
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ServletModel-13 04:32:26,793 |
>   ERROR | mix-4.5.1/deploy | RegisterWebAppVisitorWC          | 175 -
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 1.0.12.1 | Registration
>   exception. Skipping. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener not found by
>   IGE_INTEGRATION [226]     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_45]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:670)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1654)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:909)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:194)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_45]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.newInstance(RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.java:221)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.visit(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:269)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:561)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:170)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:155)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:119)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.setService(ReplaceableService.java:114)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.access$100(ReplaceableService.java:28)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService$CollectionListener.serviceAdded(ReplaceableService.java:183)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection$Tracker.addingService(ServiceCollection.java:181)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection.onStart(ServiceCollection.java:139)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.onStart(ReplaceableService.java:146)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:81)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.doPublish(WebXmlObserver.java:304)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.addingEntries(WebXmlObserver.java:153)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.register(BundleWatcher.java:186)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.access$000(BundleWatcher.java:45)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher$1.bundleChanged(BundleWatcher.java:127)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:729)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:610)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3879)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1850)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:927)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1244)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1216)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:505)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>   04:32:26,794 | ERROR | mix-4.5.1/deploy | RegisterWebAppVisitorWC
>   | 175 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 1.0.12.1 |
>   Registration exception. Skipping. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet not found by
>   IGE_INTEGRATION [226]     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_45]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:670)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1654)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:909)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:194)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_45]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.newInstance(RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.java:221)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.visit(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:200)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:583)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:170)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:155)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:119)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.setService(ReplaceableService.java:114)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.access$100(ReplaceableService.java:28)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService$CollectionListener.serviceAdded(ReplaceableService.java:183)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection$Tracker.addingService(ServiceCollection.java:181)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)[karaf.jar:2.2.10]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection.onStart(ServiceCollection.java:139)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.onStart(ReplaceableService.java:146)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:81)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.doPublish(WebXmlObserver.java:304)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.addingEntries(WebXmlObserver.java:153)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.register(BundleWatcher.java:186)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.access$000(BundleWatcher.java:45)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher$1.bundleChanged(BundleWatcher.java:127)[175:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.12.1]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:729)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:610)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3879)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1850)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:927)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1244)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1216)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:505)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]

After this when I hit jsp file, that goes fine, I can see that jsp file. But when I try to call Rest URL, it prompts an error that:

```
Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

But locally when I run the application by jetty:run everything works fine.

I have posted this question here as well:

[Apache Karaf, WAR Deployment Issue](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/WAR-deployment-on-Service-Mix-td4029485.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
RegisterWebAppVisitorWC | 175 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 1.0.12.1 | Registration exception. Skipping. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener not found by IGE_INTEGRATION [226] at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:] at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:] at
```

tells me that your missing some spring jars, how is your WAR built, as a
std. WAR or as a WAB (War with OSGi Manifest). 
If it's the second do you have all required imports resolved?
If it's the first do you have all required jars included in your war and at the 
right spot WEB-INF/lib. 
Does your WAR contain some "not allowed" jars in it like servlet.jar, etc...

*EDIT:*
Ok, your war does contain all jars in the lib folder but you only define the WEB-INF/classes as part of your Bundle-ClassPath, that's what you're missing. You need to define the complete classpath including the jars in your lib folder. So your Bundle-ClassPath needs to look like:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes, WEB-INF/lib/spring-core.jar, ...
```

Comment: My war contains all the jars in the lib folder. No, my war doesn't contain nor allowed jars.

Comment: This is my MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Name: IINT
Bundle-SymbolicName: IINT
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: .,WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-Vendor: RA
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.6


and this is my POM.XML

http://pastebin.com/52d3paM5

Comment: Any further help please?

Comment: I am still unable to deploy war successfully, I tried the way you told but the error stays. Can you help me more specifically? If i send you the war please?

Comment: if you post your question and your war to the karaf mailing list, I might have some time this evening (GMT+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Achim, I have posted the question there and war as well. The link to that is: http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/WAR-deployment-on-Service-Mix-td4029485.html 

It says, the post has not yet been accepted by mailing list yet.
Hopefully, will be selected till your evening.